# Is there a Mathematic function to only calculate the lower triangle matrix?

Tags: matrix

I am performing comparisons to generate a similarity matrix.  The comparisons in the upper triangle matrix are the inverse of the ones in the lower triangle matrix but they result in the same value.  My actual code is much more complicated than that shown below but the example code below demonstrates the point.

```
inmatrix = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}};
multifunc = Function[x, Abs[Part[x, 1] - Part[x, 2]]];
comparisons = Tuples[inmatrix, 2];
outmatrix = Map[multifunc, comparisons]
outmatrix2 = Partition[outmatrix, 4]
MatrixForm[outmatrix2]
```

This results in the matrix:
[image]

There is no need to calculate both the lower and upper triangle matrix because the values are redundant.  Is there a simple way to calculate only the upper or lower triangle matrix?

Comment: Have you looked st DistanceMatrix? You can specify your own DistanceFunction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is with `Subsets`.

These are the items that you wish to compute a distance between. Let the distance function be `distFun`.

The indices of the upper triangular part are `Subsets[Range@Length[items], {2}]`

The matrix can be obtained as

```
Normal@SparseArray[
  # -> distFun @@ Part[items, #] & /@ Subsets[Range@Length[items], {2}]
]
```

This would make sense if `distFun` takes long to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

Giving your distance function the `Orderless` attribute and applying memoization you make sure that the function will be only called for one triangular side of the matrix (and the diagonal). You can use `Outer` to create the matrix.

```
ClearAll[multifunc]
multifunc[x_, y_] := multifunc[x, y] = Abs[x - y];
SetAttributes[multifunc, Orderless]

inmatrix = {1, 2, 3, 4};
(comparisons = Outer[multifunc, inmatrix, inmatrix, 1] )//MatrixForm
```

[image]